# How to implement custom blend mode in SDL2?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, blending, color-blending, blend-mode

SDL2 provides by default 3 [blend modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes): alpha blend, additive, and multiply.

However I need to render filled rectangles using the Linear Light blend mode.

Is this possible to implement using OpenGL, or as a combination of the 3 built-in blend modes, or should I convert all my `SDL_Texture`s to `SDL_Surface`s and modify the pixel values manually?

Comment: Keep an instance of your Surface, modify this surface and make a texture out of it. The texture is on the memory near your GPU.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm probably going to do.

Comment: Readback and software recalculation is likely to be enormously slow. You can render to texture and then combine two textures with a shader and have very good performance with that. However it is not exactly what blending does (rendering multiple shapes should all blend in draw order, not just once).

Answer (score 3):

SDL 2.0.6 introduced the function SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode allowing you to create a new blend mode for 2D rendering.

Here is the doc entry: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode